# Looking for space series with sailing ship

Tags: story-identification

I remember an animated series back in the early 80s that included a space ship that looked like an old sailing ship. Thought it was Starfleet but none of the clips I can find include this ship. Ideas?

Comment: Did this animated series seem to be a US cartoon, Japanese/Anime, or anything else? Do you remember anything about any of the characters at all?

Comment: This user hasn't been back since asking the question in the first place :-((

Comment: I have been thinking about the same thing for YEARS!!! It was sort of a pirate ship leading a rag-tag gathering of other ships behind it. (similar to Battlestar galactica series) But the capitan was white beard? Definitely similar to maybe half pirate/half metal bottom. Like belonged in the ocean but was in space. I watched it before school, so 7am weekdays? If was in color also.

Comment: @Mark Mendenhall, there was a something resembling this in Bravestarr. I was of your age that time too, so I might be wrong

Answer (score 9):

I know of two possible answers (other than  Jayce given by another user).

**First Answer**

That could be [Captain Harlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Harlock) (also called "Captain Herlock" in UK or "Albator" in France).  He is a space Pirate or Privateer. The series was created by Leiji Matsumoto.

[image: Captain Harlock]

*Added after 2 comments*

His ship called [Arcadia](http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/016478/files/004518242/aoshima-vaisseau-arcadia-albator-84.jpg) (sometimes Atlantis) came in [several different version](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcadia_%28vaisseau%29), but essentially a green or blue type. It always had the stern of an ancient galleon, probably early 18th century. Late 18th century is less ornate (see [Lafayette's ship](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hermione_4.JPG)). Captain Harlock is often shown holding the wheeel at the helm, which is much like the wooden wheel of a sailship (but wheels are found on other ships).

---

**Second Answer**

There is actually a space ship in the form of a sailship with sails in the [Star Fleet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0307741/)
(in 2 words, not one) series, aka Bomber X.  It is [The Skull](http://www.sfxb.co.uk/mecha/theskull.html), captained by
Captain Halley. It appears in the [5th episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3154174/), and in others.

[image: The Skull]

The date is 1982. But the available information seems scarce.

Comment: None of the google image results for this show a ship with sails - are you sure?  : )

Comment: @user1158692 - Captain Harlock's ship *Arcadia* didn't have sails, but it was obviously modeled after an old sailing ship from the age of sail. The OP didn't mention the ship had *actual* sails.

Comment: I recall Bravestarr had an episode or two with sick-looking space stations resembling late XIX century battleships

Answer (score 6):

[Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors) had a spaceship that, while not really looking like a sailing ship, had solar panels that looked like sails, that gave it a similar outline.

[image: Jayce Ship]

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be looking for [Odin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin:_Photon_Sailer_Starlight)

Created in the mid-80s, all the ships look like sailing ships.  :)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[The Bobobobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobobobs)

> Set in the distant past, the plot revolves around a group of nomadic miniature humanoids known as the Bobobobs, who live in a part of the universe far away from the Earth. One crew of these Bobobobs, led by Bob Wouter, the captain, sets sail in the Bobular Quest, their spaceship, described as a "galleon with a protective dome".[2] They head towards Earth where they plan to save the humans from being terrorised by dinosaurs. Along the way they
>   encounter a variety of different alien species, some of which are hostile, and use their psychic powers, such as their ability to become invisible and to teleport, to aid them.

I remember watching this in the early nineties. It's an European cartoon.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a movie instead of a TV series it may be Treasure Planet. I hope this was helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate :) Why Treasure Planet? What are the similarities? Etc.

Comment: @AndresF. - I've added a pic that may prove enlightening

Comment: But it's too recent to be remembered as a TV series from the 80's

Answer (score 0):

There *was* a ship in Star Fleet/X-Bomber that was a sailing ship, called The Skull. There's a few images of it and a description of both the ship and how it ties into the plot at http://www.sfxb.co.uk/mecha/theskull.html.