# 80's animated space adventure

Tags: story-identification

I remember a movie, or maybe pilot episode of a show that involved spaceships that looked like old pirate ships with sails.

The lead character was inheriting his father's legacy or something; his old ship and gear. A cool laser sword; "when the blade glows red, it can cut through anything" and a ring that could either make a shield (maybe sort of eagle shaped?) or deliver a power punch.

I think he crashed his ship looking for this stuff, and wanted to convert the old ship to be spaceworthy. I seem to remember him asking his first mate if they had 'enough to make her fly.'

This has been driving me crazy for years. Somebody must know this.

Comment: Any of the answers over at this question match your query? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/looking-for-space-series-with-sailing-ship

Comment: Nah, not really.. That was the query that lead me to try posting here, haha, so I'd already checked out all the answers.. The deal, I think, was that the main character always flew around in his space/sail ship, and the ship they found was just a standard old sailing ship.. So they stripped the wreckage of their crashed ship and outfitted the old pirate ship as their new vessel. It was stashed in some sort of cave, much like 'the goonies', and to finally leave, they blew on a conch shell, a loads of rocks fell down, and they launched into space..

Comment: You might want to mention that you already read the question/answers in your question and none of them match - otherwise, you'll end up with the same suggestions again here

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't what you're looking for, but the long-running webcomic [Sluggy Freelance](http://sluggy.com) has featured several of those elements at various times --the pirate ship spacecraft in the "Oceans Unmoving" story arc and the glowing red sword at various points throughout its run.

Comment: I remember this too. He ends up fighting his father who he doesn't know is his father.

Comment: any chance this is Gatchaman F? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nI_YZSgDVdQ

Answer (score 7):

This sounds a lot like [Ulysses 31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_31)

Note the ring-shield, laser sword, spaceship with sails, etc, etc

Comment: I was watching exactly that just last night, haha.. I'm not sure? Unless there's some sort of flashback episode.. I only got as far as episode 8.. There are a lot of similarities.. But it didn't Sound like the right one either.. Those lines are pretty key, haha.. They're the things I Definitely remember happening.. The sword could change colours, and yeah, when it went red he could "cut through Anything"... Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It kind of rings true for [*Space Pirate Captain Harlock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Pirate_Captain_Harlock), but I don't remember a lot of that stuff happening in it. Then again I saw the 2013 one. It was apparently (according to my friend) what Lucas got his inspiration from to make Star Wars. I hope it helps, but I could be WAY off.

### Trailer