# Old ('80s?) cartoon/anime with some kids who find a spaceship and go on a space journey with a princess

Tags: story-identification, anime, space, animation

Old (possibly '80s?) cartoon/anime with male kids/youngsters. I think I remember one main boy character that loves the princess, one with glasses, and a chubby one. They find a landed spaceship with flashing lights and go on a space journey on a space boat with a princess for some quest, maybe to save her kingdom. It aired in Greece and was dubbed in Greek. It was possibly an anime or cartoon. Sorry, I don't remember much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? Also, can you describe the appearance of any of the characters (such as hair colour) or the spaceship?

Comment: Hi thank you,it is not Voltron I am afraid..I watched in the early 90s. The spaceship was a massive one with multiple series of striking lights maybe there was music coming out of it too?.. Later on I think they were travelling the universe on a sort of a boat maybe with canons too? and I think something happened to one of the kids either one died or they left only one of them behind...it is all quite blurry

Comment: Are any of these what you're looking for? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46015/looking-for-space-series-with-sailing-ship

Comment: Thank you for sharing these and for your time spent searching. It is the Byeolnara samchongsa (1979) the one I was looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*Byeolnara samchongsa*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1725007/) (1979)

> Three young children are fascinated by space. One night they saw a
> flying object crashing into the forest. Ruru, the king of the children
> of the kingdom of the space is on board. Ruru invites the three
> musketeers in his realm of space. During this journey, a terrible
> battle began in space to destroy the enemy in the middle of a meteor
> shower.

I was searching it to all these years!

Comment: And, if this is the correct answer, a duplicate of [70's/80's anime where the heroes travel on a spaceship to rescue a princess](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213711/70s-80s-anime-where-the-heroes-travel-on-a-spaceship-to-rescue-a-princess)

Comment: WOW!!I can't beleive this!!It is indeed ''Byeolnara samchongsa (1979)'' I am shocked and amazed you managed find this,thank you sooooooooo much you are a hero!!

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to mind is the old [Voltron:Defender of the Universe](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086824/). It aired from 1984-1985, with young male boys (a chubby one and one with glasses), they were helping a princess and travelled in a spaceship. I think a [greek dub](https://www.greekdubdb.com/title?id=1168) was made of it too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for searching. It is the Byeolnara samchongsa (1979) the one I was looking for

Comment: @JoB.S then you should probably uncheckmark mine and mark the other answer as correct :)